# What happens when no chromosomes satisfy the contraints?

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I've found [this page from the R blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/) where there is an example of how the `genalg` library works.

I've written a piece of code, mainly copy-pasted from the page linked above. What I'm expecting from the code is that no chromosome is a good solution and I've been wondering what happens when, in theory, all the chromosomes should be discarded. It seems that the algorithm is always able to return a solution but which solution is a solution that does not satisfy the constraints?

What I can imagine is that the algorithm should always return a chromosome made of only zeroes. I tried to run it *several* times but it does not happen, i.e. it returns also ones, in the chromosome sequence. But, how is this possible? What am I missing? Does anyone have more experience than me, with respect to genetic algorithms in general and the `genalg` library for R, in particular?

The code:

```
library("genalg");

evalFunc <- function(x) {
    current_solution_survivalpoints <- x %*% dataset$survivalpoints;
    current_solution_weight <- x %*% dataset$weight;
    if (current_solution_weight > weightlimit){
        return(0);
    }
    else{
        return(-current_solution_survivalpoints);
    }
}

dataset <- data.frame(item = c("pocketknife", "beans", "potatoes", "unions", "sleeping bag", "rope", "compass"),
                survivalpoints = c(10, 20, 15, 2, 30, 10, 30),
                weight = c(5, 10, 20, 5, 12, 10, 5));

#this is the constraint that cannot be satisfied
weightlimit <- 4;

GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size = 7, popSize = 200, iters = 100, mutationChance = 0.01, evalFunc = evalFunc);
filter <- GAmodel$evaluations == min(GAmodel$evaluations);
chromosome <- GAmodel$population[filter, , drop= FALSE][1,];
print("the solution is");print(chromosome);
```